# Order citations by year and bibliography by date

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I would like to have my in-text citations ordered by date (`authoryear`), while keeping my bibliography ordered alphabetically by first author. Currently, the in-text citations simply print in the order that I type them. Is there a way of having them ordered automatically?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\bibliographystyle{amnat2-new}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\begin{document}

Here are some citations \citep{Zeh1996,Angelard2008,Burkhardt1985,Chapman1998}

\bibliography{Bibfile.bib}
\end{document}
```

I would like the text to then read:

> Here are some citations (Burkhardt 1985; Zeh 1996; Chapman 1998;
>   Angelard 2008)

Comment: I suspect that BibTeX doesn't provide enough resources (or "hooks") to allow the citation call-outs be sorted by the values of the `year` fields. It should be doable in biblatex/biber, though. How committed are you to keep using BibTeX? (Your answer may well be, "very committed, since I must use the `amnat2-new` bibliography style, which I wouldn't know how to transpose to biblatex terminology".)

Comment: I do not particularly need to use the `amnat2-new` style, so it would be useful to know how it can be done, thank you.